# dynamic data range for vba char

Tags: charts

I'm creating a graph that takes data from the range `$f$80:$q$83`, but I need `$q` to be variable. I don't want to manually update the graph.

I use the following code and it works partially, since the graph is incorrect.

```vb
Sub GraphDynRange()
'
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim x, k, y, i As Integer
    
    x = 80
    k = 83
    y = 6

    i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("$F$80:$Q$80")) + y
    Set rg = Range("$F$80", Range("$F$80").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
    
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 2").Activate
    
    With Sheets("Historico")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(x, y), .Cells(k, i))
    End With

End Sub
```

[graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu3NV.png) [graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7CtV.png) shows me the data series in the wrong way.